# How to fix box position in css irrespective to screen resolution?

Tags: html, css, positioning, screen-resolution

For the header i put: `<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>`
the script I've given in the body is:

```
<input name="search" type="text" onKeyUp="getScriptPage('box','text_content')" id="text_content" AUTOCOMPLETE="off" size="40">
```

in css the I've given id script is:

```
#box
{
  width : 270px;
  height : auto;
  overflow : auto ;
  border : 1px solid #C5C5C5;
  background : #F8F8F8;
  position : absolute;
  left : 460px;
  top : 286px;
  border-top : none;
  text-align : left;
  display : none;
}
```

the problem is when I change the screen resolution from 1366x768 to any higher ...the box placement is changed ... I just want to fix the box position irrespective to screen resolution

Comment: where do you want to "fix" it? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: do you have a box outer to your input element to simulate typing in the box ???? and do you have problem positioning it ?

Comment: Btw, you're missing a trailing slash or closing tag for your input tag.

Comment: its like an autosuggest like that of google . When you type something the box pops up showing relevant search query to what you typed.

Comment: @Aftad: I don't see your extended html anywhere. Just showing us the `<input>` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`?

http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using percentages instead of pixel values then:

```
#box
{
  width : 270px;
  height : auto;
  overflow : auto ;
  border : 1px solid #C5C5C5;
  background : #F8F8F8;
  position : absolute;
  left : 33%;
  top : 33%;
  border-top : none;
  text-align : left;
  display : none;
}
```

The percentages here are just examples - you'd need to determine where to put it relative to your desired layout by fiddling with the percentage values. Here's an example of a box positioned with percentage values: http://jsfiddle.net/RjgHy/

Comment: i did that but the position of the box displays somewhere else on a different screen resolution